# Mainframe JCL - SFTP to Globalscape on Windows Server

Tags: windows, ftp, sftp, mainframe, jcl

My department is trying to set things up within **Mainframe JCL** to **SFTP a file to Globalscape** on a Windows Server.

The most recent Globalscape requires the passing of a **key as well as a password**. We definitely don't want to pass the password in clear text. If we do, we get the message "*Supplying the password on the command line is VERY insecure*"

Example of JCL similar to what we are using:

```
//SFTP2    EXEC PGM=AZXBAQT1,                                          
//             REGION=0M,                                              
//             PARM='PGM /opt3/tectia/bin/sftpgx3                        
//             -B //DD:BATCHIN --password=file://DD:PASSWD'            
//SYSTSPRT DD  SYSOUT=*                                                
//STDOUT DD SYSOUT=S,DEST=UYYY                                         
//*TDOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*                                                
//STDENV   DD  DSN=NTPROD.TECTIA.PARMLIB(SSHENV),DISP=SHR              
//PASSWD   DD  DISP=SHR,DSN=password.data.set                                                     
//BATCHIN  DD  *
```

However, the call does go through, then we get:

"*Opening connection to 'ourserver.com'.
Error: Could not connect to `ourserver.com'.
Connection open failed;  (local): Failed to open TCP connection*"
I believe this might be a firewall issue.

**We need a way to forward the password in a secure manner. In addition, we need to resolve the 'failed to open TCP' exception. Any insight greatly appreciated.**

Comment: You should fisrt solve your TCP connection problem, the see if the password is accepted the way you provide it. Try to connect to the server from TSO or a shell session. If you don't succeed, contact your network people regarding the connection failure. You simply did not provide any info that would help to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We were able to resolve both of these issues.